# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: uses parameter name 'order.id' which isn't a valid Python identifier

Tags: python, django

when i'm running the command `python manage.py runserver` i'm getting an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: URL route 'order_detail/<int:order.id>/' uses parameter name 'order.id' which isn't a valid Python identifier.
```

#### views.py

```
def order_detail(request, order_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        email = str(request.user.email)
        order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id, emailAddress=email)
        order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
    return render(request, 'store/order_detail.html', {'order': order, 'order_items': order_items})
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.home, name='home')
   path('order/<int:order.id>/', views.order_detail, name='order_detail'),
]
```

#### template file detail.html

```
{% for order in order_details %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ order.created|date:"d M Y" }}</td>
  <td>{{ order.total }}</td>
  <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Complete</td>
  <td><a href="{% url 'order_detail' order.id %}">View Order</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`order.id` is not a valid python identifier, and thus not valid as parameter for route. `.`, `-` among others are not accepted characters in python identifiers.

it should be `order_id` as it's defined in your view function `order_detail(request, order_id)`

change this route

```
   path('order/<int:order.id>/', views.order_detail, name='order_detail'),
```

to

```
   path('order/<int:order_id>/', views.order_detail, name='order_detail'),
```

and in your template it should be

```
<td><a href="{% url 'order_detail' order_id=order.id %}">View Order</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your path from this:
path('order/int:order.id/', views.order_detail, name='order_detail')

To this:
path('order/int:order.id', views.order_detail, name='order_detail')